# How to use MS DOS-defined aliases in Powershell

Tags: powershell, alias, ms-dos, aliases

I have some aliases that are defined in MS Dos style, how can I invoke those from Powershell? When I type "alias" from Powershell prompt, I can see my aliases defined there but when I try to call them by just typing their names, Powershell complains with a message like "The term 'whatever' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet...".

Comment: Please add an example.

Comment: @pk I believe these are aliases set up via `doskey`. Example: http://superuser.com/questions/49170/create-an-alias-in-windows-xp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Getting doskey macros to work in PowerShell](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrewarnottms/archive/2007/07/09/getting-doskey-macros-to-work-in-powershell.aspx):

```
PS> doskey /exename=powershell.exe cd\home=pushd $env:USERPROFILE\$*
```

and

```
PS> doskey /exename=powershell.exe /MACROFILE=mymacros.txt
```

See that page for more information.

Comment: I've read that article. This one doesn't seem to work for me. I.e., after running `doskey /exename=powershell.exe cd\home=pushd $env:USERPROFILE\$*` in PowerShell, if I type `cd\home` I get an error `cd\home : The module 'cd' could not be loaded.`